# If cell value contains value from list (wildcard match), retrieve data from a specific column

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I am using Google Sheets and have two sheets, Sheet1 and Sheet2. I want to look if a certain cell in Sheet1 contains a value from column A in Sheet2. The match should be done via wildcard `*value*`. If there is a match, the corresponding value in column B (Sheet 2) should be retrieved.

**Sheet2 looks like this:** Two columns, column A is what I want to search for and column B is what I want to return if there is a match.

```
| Search               | Return        |
|:---------------------|:--------------|
| dog                  | Dog           |
| hound                | Dog           |
| juice                | Beverage      |
| cola                 | Beverage      |
```

**Sheet1 looks like this**, column A contains names of different things and column B contains a google sheeet formula.

```
| Name                 | Type          |
|:---------------------|:--------------|
| Coca-Cola            | {formula}     |
| Nuka-Cola            | {formula}     |
| Slurp Juice          | {formula}     |
| Dog                  | {formula}     |
| Cola Juice           | {formula}     |
| Doggo                | {formula}     |
| Doge                 | {formula}     |
| American Foxhound    | {formula}     |
| Mountain Dog         | {formula}     |
| The Hound            | {formula}     |
```

**Sheet1 should look like this in the end**, see column B.

```
| Name                 | Type          |
|:---------------------|:--------------|
| Coca-Cola            | Beverage      |
| Nuka-Cola            | Beverage      |
| Slurp Juice          | Beverage      |
| Dog                  | Dog           |
| Cola Juice           | Beverage      |
| Doggo                | Dog           |
| Doge                 | Dog           |
| American Foxhound    | Dog           |
| Mountain Dog         | Dog           |
| The Hound            | Dog           |
```

This is way beyond my google sheet formula skills. Right now I have the following formula in Sheet1, which did something similar before - but dosen't work at all now:
`=LOOKUP(2^15;SEARCH(Sheet2!A:A;*A2*);Sheet2!B:B`.

If possible, I don't want to use absolute references for this, since I don't know how long Sheet2 is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(D2:D),
 LOWER(TEXTJOIN("|", 1, SORT(A2:A, 1, 0))))), A2:B, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Tested, and it works perfectly. However, for my purpose I need to have formulas on each row in Sheet1, column B. I changed your solution to the following `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(D2);
 LOWER(TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; SORT(A:A; 1; 0))))); A:B; 2; 0)))` and it seems to be working.

Comment: in that case you need just: `=IFNA(VLOOKUP(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(D2); LOWER(TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; SORT(A:A; 1; 0))))); A:B; 2; 0))`